# Null check operator error with tflite Flutter

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, dart, tensorflow-lite

The following code causes this error `Null check operator used on a null value` but I cannot figure out why.

```dart
import 'package:tflite_flutter/tflite_flutter.dart';

final modelFile = 'model.tflite';

void main() async {
  foo();
}

void foo() async {
  Interpreter inter = await Interpreter.fromAsset(modelFile);
}
```

The model exists at the correct location and I have tried multiple other locations just in case. The file is in my `pubspec.yaml` and I have tried multiple variations just in case. Not sure if I need to provide more parameters or something but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Just to test if it was an issue with me not placing the file in the correct location, or not referencing it in the `pubspec.yaml` I tested other assets such as Images and Text files in the same location and they loaded perfectly fine.

Comment: Is your tflite model directly in the directory or it's inside asset folder?

Comment: @DeepakLohmod it's in the asset folder but I tried multiple locations just in case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not exported the file. To fix to go to pubspec.yaml and find these lines:

```
flutter:

  assets:
    - model.tflite
```

And make sure you are specifying the correct file location when adding it through pubscpec. After that uninstall the app, do flutter clean, flutter pub get and it should work

Comment: I did that, I have tried multiple variations too. I tried using the file name like you indicate and I have tried the directory.

Answer (score 0):

I assumer the directory containing the model is named as "assets".

```
import 'package:tflite_flutter/tflite_flutter.dart';

final modelFile = 'assets/model.tflite';

void main() async {
  foo();
}

void foo() async {
  Interpreter inter = await Interpreter.fromAsset(modelFile);
}
```

Code for pubspec:-

```
flutter:

  assets:
    - assets/model.tflite
```

Comment: According to [this](https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter) the modelFile just needs to be `model.tflite` but just in case I tried both. Neither work.